# jQuery stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: jquery

I have a website with a audio player and I'm trying to improve the random option by adding an option that would allow the user to change the minimum amount of music that needs to be played in order for the same music to get selected again

so basically:
Song N°15 -> at least X different songs -> Song N°15

and you would be able to change X with a slider

this is the code I currently have:

```
var Song = 1;
var tweenSongs = 3;
var songList = [];
var songListNumber = 1;

function randomizeTrack() {
    Song = Math.floor((Math.random() * songTotal) + 1);

    if (songListNumber - tweenSongs < 1) {
        for (i=0; i <= tweenSongs - 1; i++) {
            if (Song == songList[songListNumber - i]) {
                randomizeTrack()
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (i=0; songListNumber != 0; i++) {
            if (Song == songList[songListNumber - i]) {
                randomizeTrack()
            }
        }
    }

    songList[songListNumber] = Song;
    songListNumber++;
}
```

the problem:

after the third song, the webpage freezes and I need to restart it, so there's an infinite loop in there but I've confused myself with my own code, does anybody know what's causing this infinite loop.

[here's a link to the website with the problem](http://googledrive.com/host/0ByBwY60ZsbQpZjFJaDhTQlRfdTg/)

Comment: My guess is that one of your `if` conditions is always "true" so you're recursively calling `randomizeTrack()` endlessly. If you've confused yourself with your own code, it's probably time to rewrite it.

Comment: the thing is, I just wrote that code

Comment: You're also probably never getting to the end of your function, so `songListNumber` never changes.

Comment: it works the first three times, so it does change

Comment: If you can isolate the code and set some defaults to get it "working" in a jsfiddle that'd help people troubleshoot it.

Comment: I've added a link to the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `else` case you're checking against songListNumber not being 0, and after a single song it's never 0 again, so the loop is infinite.

I would remove the recursion, and just do the checking for "too recent" in a single loop.  Just check the end of the list, making sure you stop either once you've checked the entire list, or gone past the number of `tweenSongs`

```
function randomizeTrack() {

    var tooRecent = false;

    do
    {
        Song = Math.floor((Math.random() * songTotal) + 1);

        tooRecent = false;
        for (var i=0; i < tweenSongs && i < songListNumber; i++)
        {
            if (songList[songListNumber - 1 - i] == Song)
            {
                // we can stop searching
                tooRecent = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    while (tooRecent);

    songList[songListNumber] = Song;
    songListNumber++;
}
```

I think you also need to initialize `songListNumber` to `0` rather than `1`. The first time through you're setting the *second* element of the initially empty array and skipping over `songList[0]`

Comment: Song is the number of the current song, songListNumber is the number of songs that have been played total, I'm trying to look through the last `tweenSongs` songs to see if one of them is the same song as the one that was randomly picked

Comment: Right - my first version was kind of tortured logic. I cleaned it up to more closely match yours. The infinite part is the fact that you're checking songListNumber in your loop - you need to be checking against the loop variable instead.  Personally, I would probably write this without the recursion, just in a `do - while (tooRecent)` loop instead.

Comment: I've tried the code you've cleaned up and it goes into an infinite loop after the fifth song

Comment: also, for the `do - while`, you mean randomize the song while `Song == songList[songListNumber - tweenSongs, songListNumber]`?

Comment: Reworked my answer to just use a do-while rather than recursion.

Comment: Cool. You could also have gotten there with a recursive solution - I think you were just checking the wrong field in your while loop, but I'm going to favor the simplest solution every time.

Comment: yup, plus, I might have to present this at some point so it's better if I can easily explain it

Answer (score 0):

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var Song = 1;
var tweenSongs = 10;
var songList = [];
var songListNumber = 1;

while(songList.length<=tweenSongs){

 Song = Math.floor((Math.random() * tweenSongs) + 1);
    if(!inArray(Song,songList)){
        songList[songListNumber]=Song;
        songListNumber++
                 }

}

console.log(songList);
```

Comment: changing it to songListNumber > 0 did not help sadly

Comment: i will try again. if no one answer before

Comment: I cant find where is the issue so I did new code to give you random number in array I hope this help you